# commandinfokationfailure, anybody knows how to fix this bug?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I have this error when trying to build in unity3d:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.
D:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "D:/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-21\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages 

stderr[
ERROR: No argument supplied for '--extra-packages' option
Android Asset Packaging Tool
```

I tried reinstalling the jdk, android sdk, and reimporting the package itself but I am  getting this same error. Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Go here for info on installing SDKs.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html
***Use the SDK manager to download the latest version of the build tools***

***Make sure your version of the android build tools is up to date.***

Comment: I have everything up to date, I have all the packages installed. I got unity 4.6, java 8 32 bit and on mac(ofcourse 64 bit).

Comment: OK. if your absolutely sure you've opened up the tools folder in the SDK Manager and installed the Android SDK Build tools 21.1.1  then it may be worth looking through the android setup instructions in the Unity3D Documentation using  [this link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html)